# How to send "applause" (repeatable "like-esque" action) through Facebook API?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, codeigniter

I'm trying to incorporate Facebook features into a site.  I'm decent with JS and PHP .. the site is based on CodeIgniter, and so far I have implemented the JS SDK, but have seen no reason to implement the PHP SDK.

I have no previous experience with Facebook integration.  It's hard to find *current* info online, so I'll ask here.

What I have is a site geared towards live jazz musicians.  Musicians have set up profiles, and I have now added a field to save their Facebook ID in SQL as well.  The site presents a large datagrid of the players, sortable in various ways, with nifty AJAXy ways to bring up extra info.

What I would like to do is have "audience members" also be able to visit the site at gigs, login, and send "applause" to individual players.  It's not "liking", since I want them to be able to applaud the same players on different nights. (with a time differential). The "applause" will also be stored onsite as a "points system".

I am doing my research, just looking for a helpful nudge in the right direction.

1. What form/mechanism can the "applause" take?
2. Is it possible for the "audience member" to trigger an action that posts on his wall, as well as the wall of the musician he applauds?
3. Is it possible to achieve this just with the JS SDK?

---

**EDIT***

Just to clarify - I would like to eventually include all live musicians in a city and to somehow give them "scoring" based on good performances/gigs.  Not just one-off "likes"/"I'm a fan" indicators.  But repeat-able "you played really well tonight" points.

Comment: This sounds like a really good way to get FB to revoke your developer privileges. They punish users for repeated liking of things through normal clicking, why would they allow an app to do it? Or am I not understanding what you mean by repeated?

Comment: Ok.  Good to hear this may be a problem.  But I thought of restricting to one "applause" per player per night.  Example: I am "audience" and out of 12 players at a session the sax player and drummer are best so I give them "applause".  Next week it is the guitarist.  The week after, it is the drummer *again*.  Is there a way to realize this idea?  --- and remember, I said a *different* mechanism than "like"-ing.

Comment: Okay, that's a little different from what I took the title to mean. Probably the best way to do it would be to use some sort of automated post to the players wall. Something like "John Doe applauded you on December 12th, 2012" or something similar, then just store the points on your site as you said. I would also check if the person had liked the performer and if they hadn't do that too.

Comment: @RickCalder Ah.. yeah, I see how that was unclear and I have edited it.  I like your idea, and I like the idea of a custom action above, as well.  I'm assuming I could post to the "audience member" *and* performer's wall as well?

Comment: @phwd I guess your answer is really the way forward.  I just hadn't looked at custom actions yet, but it seems that is pretty much what I need.  If you post this again I can mark you as the solution.